# Dúvida com Assembly - Alterar valor Address

Tags: assembly

Sou iniciante em Assembly e C, e eu preciso alterar o valor de um address de um arquivo .exe

```
004864D2   . C785 5CFCFFFF F8020000    MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-3A4],2F8
```

Eu tentei da seguinte forma com o C

```
__declspec(naked) void HookPatch::ChangeCliver_02()
{
    static const INT32 szContinue = 0x0048652C;
    __asm
    {
        MOV DWORD PTR SS : [EBP - 0x03A4], 0x1DF2
        JMP szContinue
    }
}
```

Quando o executo o programa com o OllyDbg a linha citada é apagada.

Comment: Por favor, edite o título da sua pergunta e coloque algo que sintetize o seu problema. A ideia do título é justamente informar sobre o que é a questão antes mesmo de acessá-la e facilitar nas buscas do site. O título atual falha nesses aspectos.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.